# Ethernet card missing - no changes to the system

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm really confused here, have searched but haven't found an answer.  I have an old PC that I repurposed into a gaming Linux box for my kids (Ubuntu 16.04).  Everything worked fine for over a week, but suddenly, there's no network connection - and I haven't made any changes to the system.

```
ifconfig
```

just shows the lo interface.

```
lspci
```

doesn't show any networking adapter at all...

Inspection of the back of the PC shows a single amber light on the upper left of the network jack.  No blinking, no change whether the cable is plugged in or not...

I haven't made any changes to the system, and my boys aren't old enough to know what Linux is (let alone do damage).  System is password protected with a P/W they don't know.

Help!

Comment: It could be the card has failed (ie. hardware error).  You could try another 'live' system to confirm its not your Ubuntu (even your install media) though if its dying, it may sometimes work, sometimes not...

Comment: It's somewhat old, but shows up in the bios...  Then again, bios is ancient so it's probably not that dynamic - the old-school bios that's been around since DOS.

Comment: I'd just boot a 'live' system and see what responses you have there. If it can use the networking card without issue it looks bad for your installed Ubuntu (config change, update or whatever -- unless its a failing sometimes-ok NIC which is why I added that to my comment).  ((Process of elimination to eliminate hardware failure...))

Comment: Live boot of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS that was used to originally install the host OS (and had network connectivity) does not have any network cards either. through lsconfig and lspci.  Declaring the hardware dead.

Comment: Open the PC, loosen the retaining screw, and reseat the ethernet card, tighten the retaining screw.